# MySQL вернуть подстроку из строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mysql

Добрый день, есть вот такой запрос

```
    SELECT  substring(memo, instr(memo, 'урожен'), 50) FROM persons.person;
    ->
    'уроженец д. Наволок Волховского р-на Лен. обл., ру'
    'уроженец с. Белое Оредежского р-на Лен. обл., русс'
    'уроженец г. Казань, русский, беспартийный, ст. инж'
```

нужно изменить запрос так, чтобы он возвращал подстроки между **'уроженец'** и **запятой** (ближайшей от слова уроженец). Т. е  *д. Наволок Волховского р-на Лен. обл.*

Comment: Решил вот так
SELECT 
    substring(memo,
        instr(memo, 'урожен'),
        instr(substring(memo,
                    instr(memo, 'урожен'),
                    150),
                ','))
FROM
    persons.person;
Результат-> 'уроженец д. Чембилей Курмышского у. Симбирской губ.,'
Подскажите как того-же самого добиться регуляркой? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substring(memo, instr(memo, 'уроженец') + strlen('уроженец'), instr(memo, ','))
```

Comment: SELECT lname, substring(memo, instr(memo, 'уроженец') + strlen('уроженец'), instr(memo, ',')) FROM persons.person
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION persons.strlen does not exist 0,000 sec